# Visual Studio 2010 Static Code Analysis in 2008 Projects

Tags: visual-studio, static-analysis

If VS2010 is installed alongside VS2008, is there a way to incorporate VS2010 static code analysis within projects being developed in VS2008? We would like to use the additional code analysis rules that ship with VS2010.

I'm on a project where we have a primary solution developed with VS2010 and a satellite .NET Compact Framework solution developed with VS2008. We are using Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2010 to create a unified continuous integration build. However, the VS2008 solution is being run against VS2010 static code analysis and generates additional warnings that we don't see in VS2008.